# Easy way to find out if this wall is load bearing? (double top plate, but parallel with trusses) with pictures

Tags: walls, load-bearing

It's a single story house (but this is an addition done in the 80's I think).  I know a double top plate usually means it's load bearing, but parallel with trusses means it's usually not load bearing.  Any easy way to tell for sure?

I've attached a few pics.  Here is looking up into the ceiling and also sticking the camera above the ceiling.

[image: Looking Up and Looking Above]

Here is a shot of the full attic.

[image]

Comment: All walls on the main floor will have double top plates. They'd be different heights otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see rafters in your pics, not trusses.  Regardless, in general, you are right that bearing walls don't normally run parallel to the rafters. If it were load bearing, there should be a kneewall (2X4's) built from the rafters or a header down to the double plate you spoke off.  Also, in the basement level, you would see a beam with posts to the footers directly under the subject wall.  The only unanswered question I have is, if the addition roof is being supported to that wall? I do see in your pic a small knee wall from the rafters to something below, but not sure if that is part of the wall you want to remove.  Summary, if there are not structural supports going from the rafters to the double plate of the wall you want to remove, it most likely is not a supporting wall.

Comment: Thank you!  Meant to add that there are just joists in the basement and no beams under the wall in question. The kneewall in the picture goes to what would probably be considered an exterior wall but not in line with the wall I want to remove.  As someone else mentioned, they are probably pre-cut studs to for cost/ease/drywall.